# Boost Asio - async stack + poll

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

My application have a queue in a shared memory which is fed by another process.
My main thread is looping over io_service.poll() to detect incoming event (mainly socket ones), and I would like to be notified through io_service.poll() when something is pushed into this queue.

Before migrating to boost.asio, I used to use the following mechanism:
- extra thread polling onto the queue.
- on new element, I write into a pipe to notify main thread.
- main thread is looping over a select. On new element, pipe wakes up the select and I unstack my queue in a callback.

Is there more elegant ways to achieve similar behavior using boost.asio?

Comment: Why don't you try some [asynchronous](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html) examples from boost?

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you will probably be able to use the Windows Object Handle service

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__object_handle_service.html

Other than that I've seen some samples on integrating user-defined services here

- http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/asio.html#asio_extensions